# $_GET returns non well formed numeric value, but standard variable doesn't?

Tags: php, get, well-formed

I'm using a variable to define a color in a PHP image. Have some code.

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: image/png");
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

$width = 36;
$height = 24;
$handle = imagecreatetruecolor ($width, $height) or die ("Cannot Create image"); //image size

$black = 0x1c1c1c;           //Black
$hp = ImageColorAllocate ($handle, $_GET["red1"], $_GET["green1"], $_GET["blue1"]);
$mp = $_GET["c1"];

ImageFilledRectangle($handle, 0, 0, 12, 24, $black);
ImageFilledRectangle($handle, 13, 0, 24, 24, $hp);
ImageFilledRectangle($handle, 25, 0, 36, 24, $mp);

ImagePng ($handle);
imagedestroy ($handle);
?>
```

This produces an example image with the GD library that *should* have the ability to set two custom colors to the middle and right rectangles, with the left rectangle always being the color 0x1c1c1c, which is an off-black. The middle rectangle works fine - you're just passing three numbers to an ImageColorAllocate command, after all - but the right rectangle errors out, with a "non well formed numerical value". Why does this happen, when $black is formatted the same way? Is there a way for me to use a single variable to define a color, instead of three?

> [Wed Mar 31 15:15:02.838650 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 10089] [client
> 45.74.102.92:62479] PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /var/www/html/test.php on line 15

Comment: Do you check that you are actually being passed a `$_GET["c1"];` parameter? That may be a worth while addition ot the code. Also check it is a numeric and no an alpha or alphanumeric

Comment: Don't pass unparsed values into functions. `$hp = ImageColorAllocate ($handle, $_GET["red1"], $_GET["green1"], $_GET["blue1"]);`

Comment: Looks like I miswrote that - the right rectangle, the $mp variable, errors out when I give it the input "0x645367" or any other hexadecimal number, identical to the $black variable.

Comment: `"0x645367"` and `0x645367` are not the same value. `$_GET` will contain strings input by the user, not PHP source code which will be evaluated using its built-in number parser.

Answer (score 0):

Trolling through the online PHP manual brought me to the hexdec() function. Instead of `$mp = $_GET["c1"];` I can use `$mp = hexdec($_GET["c1"]);`, and it works like a dream. Answered my own stupid question, heh. Thank you for the hint, Quentin.